# Email Settings API Auth2.0 Update Signature

Tags: c#, api, gmail

Where am I going wrong here? When I try the URL it says: "required parameter is missing: response_type". What do I need to add to get this thing to work? And if you can provide a simple explanation that'd be awesome.

```
string client_ID = "XXXXXXX";
        string client_Secret = "XXXXXXXXXXX";
        string scope = "https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/workwearoutlet.co.uk/zak.baig/signature";
        string redirect_URI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";

        // Prepare OAuth parameters
        OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters();

        parameters.ClientId = client_ID;
        parameters.ClientSecret = client_Secret;
        parameters.Scope = scope;
        parameters.RedirectUri = redirect_URI;

        string applicationName = "signature";
        string domain = "workwearoutlet.co.uk";

        // Request authorization from the user
        string authorizationURL = OAuthUtil.CreateOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(parameters);
        Console.WriteLine(authorizationURL);
        Console.WriteLine("Please visit the URL above to authorize your OAuth " +
            "request token. Once that is complete, type in your access code to " +
            "continue...");
        parameters.AccessCode = Console.ReadLine();

        OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(parameters);
        string accessToken = parameters.AccessToken;
        Console.WriteLine("OAuth Access Token: " + accessToken);

        try
        {
            // Create a new request factory so it uses our OAuth credentials
            GOAuth2RequestFactory requestFactory = new GOAuth2RequestFactory("apps", applicationName, parameters);

            GoogleMailSettingsService service = new GoogleMailSettingsService(domain, applicationName);
            service.RequestFactory = requestFactory;

            // Update the signature for the user testUserName
            service.UpdateSignature("zak.baig@workwearoutlet.co.uk", "My tiny signature");

            Console.WriteLine(service.RetrieveSignature("zak.baig@workwearoutlet.co.uk"));
        }

        catch (AppsException a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A Google Apps error occurred.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Error code: {0}", a.ErrorCode);
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input: {0}", a.InvalidInput);
            Console.WriteLine("Reason: {0}", a.Reason);
        }
```

Answer (score -4):

I believe this would be best achieved using the PHP OAuth2 API.

This removes all issues with the badly written C# API calling functions.

Also, have you tried the search function? I have found multiple fixes to this problem.

Comment: Please don't mention that awful language. Why people still use PHP is beyond me.

Comment: @Zak Ha! People so ignorant these days thinking C# is still relevant in a web-based world. Had a good chuckle on this satire, thank you!